# Laravel: Check for Specific Pivot Relation OR no relation

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I'm using Laravel 8.0

I have two tables, Module and User, linked by a pivot table (module_user), I'm trying to work out how to list ALL of the modules using eloquent (or SQL) and if the current user has a pivot entry (e.g. they have completed the module) then it marks that, for example:

```
Module Name         Completed
###########         #########
Coding Basics       
Database Basics     Yes
```

Any suggestions?  I really have no idea how to go about this as I either retrieve ALL the linked modules/users or only the modules the current user has completed.

Thanks!!

Comment: use something like this`@foreach ($moduleData as $data)
 @if($data->pivot->isComplete){
  Yes`

Comment: Can you share your models and tried codes so we can help?

Comment: this is a many to many relationship, but it is unclear what you want to do. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many